# The last employee data does not show when compiling the code

Tags: c++, filereader, void

I'm trying to obtain the data for the last employee Bob Hu. But for some reason, it doesn’t want to show up. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong.? I try to put the calculation/display code into a function() and call it where you currently calculate/display the data and also after while() terminates. But I think I'm doing it wrong. Please help
This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void find_pay(string x)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename;
    
    // Get the filename from the user.
    cout << "Enter the filename: ";
    cin >> filename;

    // Open the file.
    inputFile.open(filename);

    // If the file successfully opened, process it.
    if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
            string data_record,prev,data_name,data_hour;
            double total = 0;
        
            while(getline(inputFile,data_record))
            {
                data_name = data_record.substr(0,30);
                data_hour = data_record.substr(31,2);
                if(prev.compare(data_name)!= 0 )
                {
                    //Calculate the gross pay, tax, net pay
                    float gross_pay = 18 * total;
                    float tax = (12 * gross_pay)/100;
                    float net_pay = gross_pay - tax;
                    if(total!= 0)
                        cout << "Employee:" << prev << "\n" "Total Hours: " << total << " Gross Pay: $ " << gross_pay << " Tax " << tax << " Net Pay: " << net_pay << endl;
                    data_name = data_record.substr(0,30);
                    prev = data_name;
                    total = 0;
                    
                }
               
                else if(prev.compare(data_name)==0)
                {
                    total += stod(data_hour);
                }
                
            }
        //close the file
        inputFile.close();
        }
}

int main()
{
    string filename;
       find_pay(filename); //call the void
   return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I got, as you see Bob Hu is missing

```
Enter the filename: /Users/normatacuri/Desktop/employeehours.txt
Employee:Jimmy Bucket                  
Total Hours: 26 Gross Pay: $ 468 Tax 56.16 Net Pay: 411.84
Employee:John Doe                      
Total Hours: 32 Gross Pay: $ 576 Tax 69.12 Net Pay: 506.88
Employee:Ann Doe                       
Total Hours: 20 Gross Pay: $ 360 Tax 43.2 Net Pay: 316.8
Employee:Mary Jones                    
Total Hours: 16 Gross Pay: $ 288 Tax 34.56 Net Pay: 253.44
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

This is the data on the file that I'm using..

```
Jimmy Bucket                   8
Jimmy Bucket                   9
Jimmy Bucket                   10
Jimmy Bucket                   7
John Doe                       8
John Doe                       8
John Doe                       8
John Doe                       8
John Doe                       8
Ann Doe                        5
Ann Doe                        5
Ann Doe                        5
Ann Doe                        5
Ann Doe                        5
Mary Jones                     4
Mary Jones                     4
Mary Jones                     4
Mary Jones                     4
Mary Jones                     4
Bob Hu                         8
Bob Hu                         8
Bob Hu                         8
Bob Hu                         8
Bob Hu                         8
```

Comment: `string filename;` then      `find_pay(filename);` is an odd design decision. Why are you passing an empty filename to this function by value? Shouldn't you have asked for the filename in `int main()` instead?

Comment: @Karla - Are you aware that the `Total Hours` are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to put the calculation/display code into a function() and call it where you currently calculate/display the data and also after while() terminates. But I think I'm doing it wrong.

You are right, you must have done it wrong, but your approach of handling the case *also after while() terminates* was good. Since you don't show this try, I can't say what you were *doing wrong*. But I can show you an alternative approach where the EOF case is also handled inside the loop - for this replacement of the `while` loop only a few statements have to be rearranged.

```
            for (; ; )
            {   bool f = (bool)getline(inputFile, data_record);
                if (!f || prev.compare(data_name = data_record.substr(0, 30)) != 0)
                {   // do this on EOF as well as new name
                    //Calculate the gross pay, tax, net pay
                    float gross_pay = 18 * total;
                    float tax = (12 * gross_pay)/100;
                    float net_pay = gross_pay - tax;
                    if (total != 0)
                        cout << "Employee:" << prev << "\n"
                                "Total Hours: " << total << " Gross Pay: $ " << gross_pay
                             << " Tax " << tax << " Net Pay: " << net_pay << endl;
                    if (!f) break;
                    prev = data_name;
                    total = 0;
                }
                total += stod(data_hour = data_record.substr(31, 2));
            }
```